# Regarding mouse events

Tags: mouseevent, mouselistener

Ihave complied in jdbc and the error is that mouseExited method doesn't override the mouseMotion., mouseMotion listener

Iam excepting an applet with the  applet screen and it should display message when mouse operation performed